# OOP inheritence, parents variable value not updated on child

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

this is simple login handler, i never have problem like this when put it on same class. then i try to put it on child class and i don't know what happening.
this is the GUI class

```
        final static Functions.F_Koneksi F_K = new Functions.F_Koneksi();
        final static Functions.F_Process F_P = new Functions.F_Process();
        final static GUIController F_GUI = new GUIController();
        protected javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordFieldPasswordLoginPane;
        protected javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldUsernameLoginPane;

        ...

        private void jButtonLoginLoginPaneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
            switch (F_GUI.DoLogin()) {
                case 1:
                    cl.show(MainPane, "BuyMovie");   
                    break;
                ...
                default:
                    LoginLabel.setText("username or password ... ");
            }
        }
```

and this is the GUIController class

```
 int DoLogin(){
        try {
            System.err.println(jTextFieldUsernameLoginPane.getText());
            char[] PassChars = jPasswordFieldPasswordLoginPane.getPassword();
            String Pass = new String(PassChars);
            return F_P.F_Login(jTextFieldUsernameLoginPane.getText(), Pass);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LoginLabel.setText("connection error");
        }
        return 3;
    }
```

and this is the F_Login method on F_Process

```
public int F_Login(String User, String Pass) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet RS = Select("select * from blablabla"); //this query work already
    int level = 8;
    if (RS.next()) {
        level = RS.getInt("Level");
    }

    return level;
}
```

the problem is when i set user and password `textfield` with right user pass its work but when user put it its not. i know something wrong with my OOP logic but i don't understand where. thank you

this is picture to make you understand what i mean

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DsrF.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXmGZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its because the `GUIController` doesn't access the same `jPasswordFieldPasswordLoginPane` that the other gui access, to do it, you must pass the object to the `GUIController` class, like pass the reference in the constructor or setter method, and in the `GUIController` you access the correct  `jPasswordFieldPasswordLoginPane`.